# Post multiple select

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to post the values of a multiple select and I only get 'Array' not the values in the email.

My select looks like this :

```
<select name="cate[]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple> 
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

And my php :

```
$val= $_POST['val'];
$toemail='test@mail.com'; // change this to your email id
$name = $val['name'];
$societe = $val['societe'];
$email = $val['email'];
$phone = $val['phone'];
$website = $val['website'];
$category = $val['cate'];
$msg = $val['msg'];

$subject = 'Contact';

$headers = "From: $email \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = "<b>Nom : </b>".$name."<br>";
$message .='<b>Societe : </b>'.$societe."<br>";
$message .='<b>Email : </b>'.$email."<br>";
$message .='<b>Telephone : </b>'.$phone."<br>";
$message .='<b>Category : </b>'.$category."<br>";
$message .='<b>Message :</b>'.$msg;
mail($toemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Thanks!";
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: `$val['cate']` is array. Try `$category = implode(', ',  $val['cate']);`

Comment: You don't need to do `name="cate[]"` since you have only one select.. `name="cate"` would probably work.

Comment: when ever we are passing data have same name it will always from an array...... so if u are passing data with same name it will create an array.... so there will be array of cate()

Comment: @Meeuuuhhhh No no no! You should use `[]` to multiple select

Comment: Guess i'm just sleeping, missed that multiple attribute there x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$val['cate']` is an array, you need to transform it in a string. The fastest way to do that with your code is:

```
$category = implode(', ', $val['cate']);
```

Comment: I'm getting a php warning when nothing is selected. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: you can both add a javascript validation to that form (client side) and a php check (server side) for that variable to exist. Fast example: `$category = $val['cate'] ? implode(', ', $val['cate']) : 'no categories';`